# Can't import from keras module 'tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v2.compat' has no attribute 'v1'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using jupyter/python (anaconda) and I was successful in loading these libraries

I tried to print tf ver

```
tf.print(tf. __ version __)
```

> <tf.Operation 'PrintV2' type=PrintV2>

and when I ran `tf.__version__` it said that I'm running TF 1.14.0' and keras ver 2.2.4-tf'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
```

However when I tried to load these two libraries I got an error *"AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v2.compat' has no attribute 'v1'"*

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Sequential
```

Answer (score 0):

Please install the latest tensorflow version using below code.

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

then try importing the above mentioned libraries using `tensorflow.keras`:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```